# Plotear en el mismo gráfico varios GAMs en R

Tags: r, model

Tengo varios modelos `GAM`. Me gustaría poder plotear varias curvas en un mismo gráfico. Alguien sabe como?

Tengo dos modelos mixtos

```
m1<-gamm4(edad~ s(altura),data=datos1)


m2<-gamm4(edad~ s(altura),data=datos2)
```

Para plotearlos:

```
plot(m1$gam, xlab= "altura", ylab="f(x)")


plot(m2$gam, xlab= "altura", ylab="f(x)")
```

Querría juntar los dos plots en uno

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, puedes añadir el tu código? lo que has intentado? Los errores que has tenido? Pasate por el [tour] y por [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: Bienvenida @Beatriz, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agregues un ejemplo mínimo (código) del modelo que quieres plotear y lo que has intentado hasta ahora para que te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Para la próxima intenta dar datos y una explicación mas concisa, para plotear varias curvas en R en un mismo Marco:

```
# Datos
curva1 <- c(7,12,28,3,41)
curva2 <- c(14,7,6,19,3)
curva3 <- c(4,7,8,10,3)


# Marco de Plot 
plot(curva1,type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "eje X", ylab = "eje Y",
     main = "multiplot")

# Añadir mas curvas
lines(curva2, type = "o", col = "blue")
lines(curva3, type = "o", col = "green")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias PeCaDe, he añadido un ejemplo, porque haciendo lo que dices no me funciona. Muchas gracias